# how can i get the url if it is like this <keyword>?

Tags: php, html

```
ebsearch/results/?solrsort=<keyword>
```

When I use `$_GET['solrsort']` it is not printing the keyword.

I tried strip_tags, but it didn't work..

Any other solution?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What do you expect? And what is filled in? we need more info if you want us to help you.

Comment: If the URL is exactly as you provided, and you are outputting that value into an HTML page, `<keyword>` will be interpreted as an invalid HTML tag and will not be displayed by your browser.  If you *View Source* on the page, you'll likely see that it showed up just fine.  If you use `print(htmlspecialchars($_GET['solrsort']));` it will likely show up as expected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
echo str_replace(array('<','>'),array('&lt;','&gt;'),$_GET['solrsort']);
```

or (better)

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['solrsort']);
```

The `<keyword>` will not be displayed in the rendered HTML output because it looks like a tag, and `strip_tags()` will remove it completely for the same reason.

Comment: I can't help but support the validity of this answer.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler: Thanks for supporting.. But may i know why can't you answer.. Your comment is exactly right...

Comment: @Fero: Wasn't sure if I was reading your question right,so felt more comfortable adding a comment.  DaveRandom was typing his answer at the same time I typed my comment and incorporated it to make it the best answer he could.  Result is a useful question and answer.  That's how it's supposed to work.  The details about names and rep aren't as important.  Cheers!

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler: Cheers! and +1 for The details about names and rep aren't as important

Comment: @@DaveRandom: If i give html tag ebsearch/results/?solrsort=<table><tr><td>test</td></tr></table> like above. It doesn't work. HTML tag is printing as it is.. Is it possible to overcome both the issues ? Thanks

Comment: You would have to set up a `if-else` structure to search for specifics and handle one or the other as appropriate. But to be honest, I have to ask whether you are taking the right approach as a whole - why would you be passing literal HTML in a GET parameter?

Answer (score 0):

```
$value=htmlentities($_GET['solrsort']);
```